# Disable keyboard <enter> on autocomplete

Tags: intellisense, monaco-editor

Currently there are two ways of accepting an autocomplete suggestion on a Monaco editor:

1. Selecting the suggestion with the mouse
2. Pressing the `<enter>` key

We want to **disable** the `<enter>` key for accepting the autocomplete suggestion and let it add a new line instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to disable that:

```
  acceptSuggestionOnEnter: "off",
```